# Opitmizingproblem with dynamic programming (creating a chart)

Tags: python, dynamic

I have a small task to do and I really dont know how to solve it: 
I have some Objects with me, which has some worth and weight, I have to decide which I want to hide and which not. Also another Problem is the weigh, which I also have to think about that because of my ong walk.

Beginning with a list of objects, which are marked by an index, worth, weight. With help of an given maximum weight, I have to determine the hightest worthful objects, which does not exceed the maximum weight. The objects can be only used only once.

I have to solve the problem with dynamic programming in python. Line index and column index are showing till when the object (weight) can be optimzed.

The Objects I are representes as pairs of worth and weight:

Example: T[3][5] is showing for example the hightest wortful Worth, which can be solved by 3 Objects which has maximum weigh of 5.

If you dont want to know only the maximum weight of the object, also other infomation, this you have to save also.In every entry T[i][j] ypu can also save if the hightest worth is there or not (with 1 or 0), because in every line only one object can exist. This flags also can be used for filling the table. Therefore the function bestChoice(chart, item) is there. Modify the function createChart(items, MAX), so that the tableentries can calculate the pairs from the createChart the worth and the explained flags ( 0 or 1)
The constructed Table T2 can with the help of the function bestChoice return the objetslist.  Implement the function, so that returnvalues should be a list, which retun 0 or 1 for the objects and if this is in the section or not.

I know the task is hard. If you have question in the task, please ask. Thanks in advance.

```
 def createChart( items , MAX ):

      #Here should be the solution for creating a chart T from a given list of objects and maximum weight

 return ?

 def bestChoice( chart , items ):

 return ?     #the selection of items should be returned here

#Testcase

items = [(3,4),(1,1),(4,5),(3,4),(2,2)]
maxWeight = 8
T = createChart( items , MAX )
# T should be this 
#[[(0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0)],
# [(0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0) (3, 1) (3, 1) (3, 1) (3, 1) (3, 1)],
# [(0, 0) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (3, 0) (4, 1) (4, 1) (4, 1) (4, 1)],
# [(0, 0) (1, 0) (1, 0) (1, 0) (3, 0) (4, 0) (5, 1) (5, 1) (5, 1)],
# [(0, 0) (1, 0) (1, 0) (1, 0) (3, 0) (4, 0) (5, 0) (5, 0) (6, 1)],
# [(0, 0) (1, 0) (2, 1) (3, 1) (3, 0) (4, 0) (5, 0) (6, 1) (7, 1)]]

#first component of the the last table item 
bestValue = T[-1][-1][0] #should return the maximal value  ( = 7 )

L = bestChoice( T , items)
#should be [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to [knapsack problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/knapsack-problem/)

Comment: Hello RohithS98, actually similar but the idea is different. Can I contact u somehow?